# Rails 3 how to get a new session id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rack

Background - I'm performing a `reset_session` before login of a new user but I also want to tie specific data to a user's session so I'm identifying each session using the `session_id`. I wanted to do this after a successful login vs some kind of `before_filter` that checks on each request but after doing a `reset_session` rails is not creating a new `session_id`.

Does anybody know how to generate a new session with a session_id after performing a `reset_session` in the same request?

```
> session.class
=> Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash
> session[:session_id]
=> "01aa3b8e7c7c26ab82b7a57e2b0f749b"
> reset_session
=> nil
> session.class
=> Hash
> session[:session_id]
=> nil
```

I saw a post saying this was bug but it was 3 years old and it didn't mention any way to get the new session id besides making another request.

```
> tmp = session.dup
=> {"session_id"=>"01aa3b8e7c7c26ab82b7a57e2b0f749b", ...}
> reset_session
=> nil
> session.replace(tmp)
=> {"session_id"=>"01aa3b8e7c7c26ab82b7a57e2b0f749b", ...}
> session[:session_id]
=> nil
```

Some other people also mentioned duplicating the session and replacing it but that doesn't create a new `session_id` either